# Não consigo usar o Android Studio (Gradle Project sync failed. Basic functionality ... )

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Procurei, procurei e não achei a solução para o meu problema.

Primeiramente colocarei as imagens da minha situação, mas de antemão já informarei que meu processador é AMD. Neste caso eu só preciso conseguir realizar build/re-build para um preview do Layout, tendo em vista que podemos emular o app de outras maneiras.

[image: Quando abro o projeto]

[image: Referência de uma possível relação com o problema]

A segunda imagem eu referenciei a partir do link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096905/android-studio-3-0-1-error-gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionality-e-g [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] que no meu Android Studio está vazio.

Versões:  
* Android Studio 3.1.4  
* Gradle 4.10  
* SDK Tools 26.1.1  
* Android Plataform Version API 28 revision 6

Comment: Favor ler [ask] e [não postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/75104)

Answer (score 0):

Vá para a pasta do seu projeto, clique com o botão direito do mouse acesse **Propriedades** e na aba **Segurança**, verifique a permissão e permita todas as permissões.

Comment: Fiz isso, entretanto nada mudou. Continuou o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de qualquer coisa verifique se o jdk está corretamente instalado no seu sistema. O Gradle não funciona sem uma versão atualizada do Java.

O que pode estar acontecendo é que o Android Studio deve estar procurando uma versão específica do Gradle e você só tem a versão 4.10 ou a versão que o Android Studio está procurando seja a 4.10 porém a pasta está corrompida.

Para corrigir:

- Feche o Android Studio .
- Com o explorador de arquivos localize a pasta do Android Studio e abra a subpasta gradle. Abra e verifique as versões existentes.
- Vá a página de [distribuições do Gradle](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/), localize as versões que seu Android não possui. Os arquivos que você precisa são aqueles que terminam com **-all.zip**. Por exemplo a versão 5.0 do Gradle será o arquivo nominado como **gradle-5.0-all.zip**.
- Faça os downloads dos arquivos. Na raiz de cada arquivo compactado estarão uma pasta com o nome da versão arraste(descompacte) a pasta para a subpasta gradle dentro da pasta do Android Studio. Repita o processo para cada versão não encontrada no seu sistema.
- Caso você suspeite que a pasta contendo a versão 4.10 esteja corrompida faça um escaneamento da mídia que hospeda a pasta e substitua a versão atual pela equivalente.
- Abra o Android Studio.
- Vá em File->Sttings->Build, Execution & Depolyment->Gradle e selecione Use Gradle Distribution.
- Em Gradle Home coloque o caminho para para pasta da versão do Gradle mais recente e de Ok.
- Aguarde enquanto Android Studio compila o Gradle. Se não der mensagem de erro funcionou. Caso de algum erro tente com outra versão até encontrar a que seja adequada ao seu sistema.